# PHP CS Fixer separates comments from trait "use" commands

Tags: laravel, php-cs-fixer, laravel-pint

I frequently use single-line comments at the end of a statement. One such case is the `use` statement at the beginning of a class definition to add traits to the class. My project uses Laravel and other packages, so I often put a URL in the comment after the `use`. In other cases, I use these comments to indicate what functionality is being added to the class by the trait.

I use PHP CS Fixer through Laravel Pint to clean up my code. I run Pint rather frequently so that I can focus on coding and clean it up later before I commit. My project's composer.json currently specifies version "^1.2" for Pint.

I `composer update`d my project a day or so and I'm running into a very disruptive problem with the aforementioned comments. They are being separated from the `use` commands they followed. For example, in one class I had this series of `use` statements:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory; // adds the factory static methods
use \App\Methods\SetCasts;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; // https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting
```

After running Pint, this code was changed to the following:

```
// adds the factory static methods
use \App\Methods\SetCasts;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; // https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting
```

I *do not* have a problem with the sorting. The problem is that the comment `// adds the factory static methods` was separated from the trait that it references.

How do I tell PHP CS Fixer to stop doing this and leave these particular comments alone?

Comment: Hello, I think you need to a PR for `// @formatter:off` and `// @formatter:on` to enable/disable php-cs by [this](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/4512#issuecomment-704747537).

Comment: I shouldn't have to tell a formatter to not format a section to keep it from separating comments from their lines and moving them around.